# Centering a custom-environment defined for width adjustment of algorithms

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, algorithmicx, algorithmic, algpseudocode

I am using the `algpseudocode` environment provided by the `algorithmicx` package in my thesis. I am wrapping the pseudocode inside the `algorithmic` environment provided by the `algorithms` package.

The issue is that the algorithm occupies the whole textwidth, which makes it a bit hard to parse (particularly comments are too far separated from the corresponding line). Furthermore, it is rather unnecessary to use the full text-width for typesetting small algorithms with one or two mathematical variables.

I would like to have a single place in my preamble to set the width of 12 algorithms in my thesis to a custom width, say `0.75\textwidth`, so that it is easily changeable. This looks like a candidate for custom environment.

To adjust width, I am using a minipage, which works if I give up the float capabilities of the algorithms (which is fine).  However, the algorithm is typeset flushed left in the page. To center it, the `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{ ...}` construct does not work with the custom environment.

Here's the MWE to illustrate the issue

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\tempcaption}{}% stores the caption
\newcommand{\templabel}{}% stores the label

\newenvironment{customalgo}[2]
{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \centering
            \gdef\tempcaption{#1}% store the caption so we can use it later
            \gdef\templabel{#2}% store the label so we can use it later
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            }%
            {%
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{\tempcaption}% use the stored caption
            \label{\templabel}
        \end{algorithm}
        \bigskip
    \end{minipage}
}%

%%%%%% End of Preamble%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\textbf{Needs centering}\par
\begin{customalgo}{Computing a Sum - needs centering}{alg:algosumnonmakebox}
    \Procedure{SUM}{ $\{x\}$}

    \State $y\gets0$
    \For{$i \gets 1 : N^{x}$} \Comment{Time series $\{x\}$ has length $N^{x}$}
    \State $y\gets y+x(i)$ \Comment{Summing up.}
    \EndFor

    \State \textbf{return}  $y$
    \EndProcedure
\end{customalgo}

\textbf{Centered with makebox}\par
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{customalgo}{Computing a Sum}{alg:algosum}
        \Procedure{SUM}{ $\{x\}$}

        \State $y\gets0$
        \For{$i \gets 1 : N^{x}$} \Comment{Time series $\{x\}$ has length $N^{x}$}
        \State $y\gets y+x(i)$ \Comment{Summing up.}
        \EndFor

        \State \textbf{return}  $y$
        \EndProcedure
    \end{customalgo}
}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: centering algo boxes]

The question is, how do I achieve centering of all algorithms without manually centering each one of these?

Comment: Place the customalgo macro, inside the \begin{center} \end{center} environment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For me the below mentioned code works perfectly. Please check the attached screen shot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\tempcaption}{}% stores the caption
\newcommand{\templabel}{}% stores the label
\newenvironment{customalgo}[2]
{%
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\gdef\tempcaption{#1}% store the caption so we can use it later
\gdef\templabel{#2}% store the label so we can use it later
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
}%
{%
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{\tempcaption}% use the stored caption
\label{\templabel}
\end{algorithm}
\bigskip
\end{minipage}
}%
%%%%%% End of Preamble%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\textbf{Needs centering}
\begin{center}
\begin{customalgo}{Computing a Sum - needs centering {alg:algosumnonmakebox}
\Procedure{SUM}{ $\{x\}$}

\State $y\gets0$
\For{$i \gets 1 : N^{x}$} \Comment{Time series $\{x\}$ has length $N^{x}$}
\State $y\gets y+x(i)$ \Comment{Summing up.}
\EndFor

\State \textbf{return}  $y$
\EndProcedure
\end{customalgo}
\end{center}
\par \textbf{Centered with makebox}
%\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
%\qquad
\begin{center}
\begin{customalgo}{Computing a Sum}{alg:algosum}
\Procedure{SUM}{ $\{x\}$}

\State $y\gets0$
\For{$i \gets 1 : N^{x}$} \Comment{Time series $\{x\}$ has length $N^{x}$}
\State $y\gets y+x(i)$ \Comment{Summing up.}
\EndFor

\State \textbf{return}  $y$
\EndProcedure
\end{customalgo}
%}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you did not understand my question. I had already achieved what I wanted __within__ the body text.  I have 12 algorithms to typeset and don't want to enclose each of them in a center environment. What I wanted to do was to declare a custom environment in the preamble that is pre-centered and readily usable multiple times within the body.